# Passing and Handling Large Objects in Workflows

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I am having to pass a fairly large object/file to a workflow when it starts (in the order of hundreds of MBs). I am using secondary storage to dump the object and have as little of it as possible in the RAM at one time on Workflow side. Is there another way to pass and handle the object which is more efficient. Does WF provide any built in function to handle such situations?

Answer (score 2):

what about passing the URI to that object instead ?

Comment: That would be problem because the workflow can run for long periods of time, persisting in between. If i pass the URI the source has to be online all the time.

Comment: the URI would have to be online all the time as the "workflow server" would have to.